# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Tags: arrays, list, indexing, bounds, out

I'm not really sure why I keep getting this error message. I'm trying to add int three to result. I don't understand why it doesn't let me do this, it seems result would be empty when I try to put three into index size1-1.

Error message: (Lines 452, 423, 11 are marked)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
at BigInt.singleDigitMultiply(BigInt.java:452)
at BigInt.multiply(BigInt.java:423)
at Dem.main(Dem.java:11)
```

Portion of BigInt class:

```
 public BigInt multiply(BigInt B2) {
BigInt result = new BigInt();
BigInt B1 = this;   
result = singleDigitMultiply(B1,B2); Line 423
    return result;

}

private BigInt singleDigitMultiply(BigInt B1, BigInt B2) {
    int size1 = B1.num.size(), size2 = B2.num.size();
    BigInt result = new BigInt();
    //result.num = new ArrayList (Collections.nCopies( size1+1, null ));
    boolean carryover = false;
    int one, two, three, four, five, carry;
    for (int i = size1-1; i >= 0; i--) {

         one = B1.num.get(i);
         two = B2.num.get(0); 

         int prod = B1.num.get(i) * B2.num.get(0);
         int prodInt = prod / 10;
         if (prod > 9) carryover = true;

         if (i == size1-1) {

         if (carryover) {
         three = prod % (prodInt * 10); 
         }
         else {
            three = prod;
         }

    System.out.println( result.num.set(size1-1,three));          Line 452
         }

    //   else {
        //   four = B1.num.get(i+1) * two;
    //       carry = four % (four - prodInt);
    //       if (four > 9) {
    //   
    //       five = prod + carry;
    //       three = five % (prodInt * 10);
    //       }
    //       else {
    //           three = prod;
    //       }
        //   result.num.add(i,three);
    //   }




    }

    return result;
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Dem {
public static void main(String[] args) {
BigInt B1 = new BigInt("55");
BigInt B2 = new BigInt("1");
BigInt D = new BigInt();
int u = 8;
int j = 10;

//BigInt J = new BigInt("u");
D = B1.multiply(B2);           Line 11
System.out.println(u/j);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably didn't set the `result.num` yet at the point in which you are trying to access this value, so  you should assign it at whatever point, either in `singleDigitMultiply(...)` method or in `BigInt` constructor, but before reading the value.

Comment: im not sure I understand what you're saying... setting result.num? how can i set the values i want in it before I have the correct value?

Comment: What I mean is that this code won't work, because result.num never receives a value, so you will get a Null Pointer Exception in result.num.set(...), but I guess this is just you didn't include it or forget to add it.

Comment: how does it not receive a value? I am attempting to set int three into index size1-1. I have another method in which this works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I would recommend you to review your code, because it's a bit confusing. For example, `public BigInt multiply(BigInt B2)` makes no sense in BigInt class. And the same for `private BigInt singleDigitMultiply(BigInt B1, BigInt B2)` in BigInt class. I would create an `Operation` class to include these methods, because this makes no sense from a semantical point of view, so it's hard to understand.